# Why am I getting a syntax error for my elif statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

Below is a copy of my code. I keep getting a syntax error for elif centralLat and centralLong. I don't understand why. I indented everything correctly. The first if easternLat and easternLong works. Why don't the elif statements for centralLong and centralLat, etc work?

For this assignment, I have to check each latitude and longitude for a specific time zone and calculate the happiness score for a timezone. This happiness score is the sum of the sentiment values of tweets in a timezone divided by the number of tweets in a timezone.

Why do I keep getting an error?

```
for line in infile2:
        line=line.rstrip()
        words=line.split()
        firststriplat=words[0].rstrip(",")
        lat=firststriplat.lstrip("[")
        lat=float(lat)
        long=words[1].rstrip("]")
        long=float(long)
        easternLat= 24.660845 <= lat and lat<=49.189787
        easternLong= -87.518395 <= long <= -67.444574
        centralLat= 24.660845 <= lat and lat<=49.189787
        centralLong= -101.998892 <= long <= -87.518395
        mountainLat=24.660845 <= lat and lat<=49.189787
        mountainLong=-115.236428 <= long <= -101.998892
        pacificLat=24.660845 <= lat and lat<=49.189787
        pacificLong= -125.242264<= long <= -115.236428
        if easternLat and easternLong:
            for word in words:
                if word in depressed:
                    depressedKeys=depressedKeys+1
                elif word in okay:
                    okayKeys=okayKeys+1
                elif word in good:
                    goodKeys=goodKeys+1
                elif word in happy:
                    happyKeys=happyKeys+1
                else:
                    pass
        numOfTweetsEastern=numOfTweetsEastern+1
        sentimentValueEastern=(depressedKeys*DEPRESSEDVALUE)+(okayKeys*OKAYVALUE)+(goodKeys*GOODVALUE)+(happyKeys*HAPPYVALUE)
        elif centralLat and centralLong:
            for word in words:
                if word in depressed:
                    depressedKeys=depressedKeys+1
                elif word in okay:
                    okayKeys=okayKeys+1
                elif word in good:
                    goodKeys=goodKeys+1
                elif word in happy:
                    happyKeys=happyKeys+1
                else:
                    pass
        numOfTweetsCentral=numOfTweetsCentral+1
        sentimentValueCentral=(depressedKeys*DEPRESSEDVALUE)+(okayKeys*OKAYVALUE)+(goodKeys*GOODVALUE)+(happyKeys*HAPPYVALUE)
        elif mountainLat and mountainLong:
             for word in words:
                if word in depressed:
                    depressedKeys=depressedKeys+1
                elif word in okay:
                    okayKeys=okayKeys+1
                elif word in good:
                    goodKeys=goodKeys+1
                elif word in happy:
                    happyKeys=happyKeys+1
                else:
                    pass
        numOfTweetsMountain=numOfTweetsMountain+1
        sentimentValueMountain=(depressedKeys*DEPRESSEDVALUE)+(okayKeys*OKAYVALUE)+(goodKeys*GOODVALUE)+(happyKeys*HAPPYVALUE)
        elif pacificLat and pacificLong:
            for word in words:
                if word in depressed:
                    depressedKeys=depressedKeys+1
                elif word in okay:
                    okayKeys=okayKeys+1
                elif word in good:
                    goodKeys=goodKeys+1
                elif word in happy:
                    happyKeys=happyKeys+1
                else:
                    pass
        numOfTweetsPacific=numOfTweetsPacific+1
        sentimentValuePacific=(depressedKeys*DEPRESSEDVALUE)+(okayKeys*OKAYVALUE)+(goodKeys*GOODVALUE)+(happyKeys*HAPPYVALUE)
        else:
            pass
    happScoreEastern=sentimentValueEastern/numOfTweetsEastern
    happScoreCentral=sentimentValueCentral/numOfTweetsCentral
    happScoreMountain=sentimentValueMountain/numOfTweetsMountain
    happScorePacific=sentimentValuePacific/numOfTweetsPacific
    print(happScoreEastern)
    print(happScoreCentral)
    print(happScoreMountain)
    print(happScorePacific)
```

Comment: `elif` needs to directly follow an `if` statement. Not follow after a couple of intervening lines.

Comment: `numOfTweetsEastern=numOfTweetsEastern+1` appears to be at the same indentation level as the preceding `if`, so the subsequent `elif` has to `if` no refer back to.

Comment: @AmandeepPasricha OK, but I'll have to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take one small portion of your code.

```
1    if easternLat and easternLong:
2        for word in words:
3            ...
4    numOfTweetsEastern=numOfTweetsEastern+1
5    sentimentValueEastern=(depressedKeys*DEPRESSEDVALUE)+(okayKeys*OKAYVALUE)+(goodKeys*GOODVALUE)+(happyKeys*HAPPYVALUE)
6    elif centralLat and centralLong:
7        for word in words:
8            ...
```

This is one `if` statement (line 1), which contains a for loop (2).
Then *after* the `if` statement are two lines (4 and 5).
Then there is the `elif` statement (6).

Those lines (4 and 5) prevent the `elif` from pairing up with the `if`.

If those lines (4 and 5) are supposed to be part of your `if` statement, they should be indented accordingly.

```
1    if easternLat and easternLong:
2        for word in words:
3            ...
4        numOfTweetsEastern=numOfTweetsEastern+1
5        sentimentValueEastern=(depressedKeys*DEPRESSEDVALUE)+(okayKeys*OKAYVALUE)+(goodKeys*GOODVALUE)+(happyKeys*HAPPYVALUE)
6    elif centralLat and centralLong:
7        for word in words:
8            ...
```

This would produce a valid `if/elif` structure.